# fail2ban autoreport to abuseipdb.com

Tags: debian-jessie, fail2ban

I want to create auto report to abuseipdb.com in fail2ban (Debian Jessie).

Here is my `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/abuseipdb.conf`:

```
[Definition]
actionstart =
actionstop =
actioncheck =
actionban = curl --data 'key=<apikey>' --data 'category=<category>' --data 'ip=<ip>' --data-urlencode 'comment=<matches>' --user-agent 'fail2ban v0.8.12' 'https://www.abuseipdb.com/report/json'
actionunban =

[Init]
apikey = xxxx
```

I edited my `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`:

```
...
# Here we use a combination of Netfilter/Iptables and IPsets
# for storing large volumes of banned IPs
#
# IPset comes in two versions. See ipset -V for which one to use
# requires the ipset package and kernel support.
[ssh-iptables-ipset4]

enabled = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto4
   abuseipdb[category=18]
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
...
```

But it does not report properly. Can anyone help me to fix the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration work on fail2ban 0.9.5.
I install it from SID. Here is the steps:
Install all dependency packages:

```
# apt-get install gamin systemd python-pyinotify python-dnspython python3-pyinotify
```

Download fail2ban 0.9.5-1 installer from SID directly from main pool http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fail2ban/fail2ban_0.9.5-1_all.deb

```
# wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fail2ban/fail2ban_0.9.5-1_all.deb
```

Remove existing fail2ban 0.8.13

```
# apt-get --purge remove fail2ban
```

You can now start to install fail2ban 0.9.5-1

```
# dpkg -i fail2ban_0.9.5-1_all.deb
```

I create a note to share all those steps above at [Debian Jessie: installing fail2ban 0.9.5-1 from SID](http://www.garasiku.web.id/web/joomla/index.php/security/104-debian-jessie-installing-fail2ban-0-9-5-1-from-sid)

Comment: thanks, this is actually the only solution that I have found.